# How to distinguish between Unrepresentative Train Dataset and minimal overfitting from a learning c

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

Is this a minimal overfitting or like unpresensitive train dataset?

However, I read it on the net but still have a problem with the graph! And then I read the following text on the net and again I asked myself is it an unpresensitive validation dataset isn't it?
"An unrepresentative validation dataset means that the validation dataset does not provide sufficient information to evaluate the ability of the model to generalize. This may occur if the validation dataset has too few examples as compared to the training dataset. This case can be identified by a learning curve for training loss that looks like a good fit (or other fits) and a learning curve for validation loss that shows noisy movements and little or no improvement."

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpTYK.jpg]